# Create increment value in Power Query based on the occurences of each value in the list

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a Table of codes in Power Query and the filenames of their pictures. So codes are duplicate values (and more than 5 some times).

I want to create column that contain an increment number  based on the occurences of the code value.

For example:
Code  -  Filename - Occurences
001    - 001.jpg - 1
001    - 001_2.jpg - 2
003    - 003.jpg - 1
004   - 004.jpg  - 1
004   - anotherpic.jpg - 2
....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If your table of codes looks something like this:

[image: Input table]

then this code:

```
let
    initialTable = Table.FromColumns({{"001", "001", "003", "004", "004"}, {"001.jpg", "001_2.jpg" , "003.jpg", "004.jpg", "anotherpic.jpg"}}, type table [Code = text, Filename = text]),
    grouped = Table.Group(initialTable, "Code", {{"toCombine", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Occurrences", 1, 1), type table}}),
    combined = Table.Combine(grouped[toCombine])
in
    combined
```

should give expected output:

[image: Output table]

You can delete/replace the first line and replace with whatever you already have. The first line is just to create an example table for demonstrative purposes.